# Get DOM element position in Katalon Studio test script

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

I'm using Katalon Studio, which in turn uses Selenium.

I can do the following to get the left position (X coordinate) of a DOM element:

`leftPosition = WebUI.getElementLeftPosition(findTestObject('MyObject'))`

I can also get the width and height of the element. However, I can't seem to find an equivalent **way of getting the element's top (Y) position**.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the top position (relative to the viewport, or possible relative to the top of the page) in Katalon?

Comment: Note: for now I use the `getPosition` function of the Selenium driver explicitly, but I suspect I'm missing a simpler way of getting the Y position in Katalon.

Comment: I guess that keyword doesn't exist: https://forum.katalon.com/t/why-is-there-no-keyword-webui-getelementtopposition-yet/13528.